# "function is not defined" after document.write called in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here is the code:

```
function getTime(j){
  var stopClock= new Date();
  delta[parseInt(j)]=stopClock.getMilliseconds()-start.getMilliseconds();
 }

 //REST OF THE CODE!!
function func(){
{
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
     start = new Date();
     document.write('<img src="'+URL[i]+'" width="1" height="1" alt="" onload="getTime('+i+');"/>');
    }
 }

 //SOME CODE

setTimeout(function() {
   func();
},100);
```

However I got this error: getTime is not defined

if I declare getTime like this:

```
 document.getTime= function (j)
```

There is no error but it never execute that function.

If I remover the setTimeout, it will work with no problem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe the issue is that document.write "re-opens" the document (whatever that means), as setTimeout happens after the document "has been closed". This leads the different behavior in different browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're destroying the DOM with your `document.write` call.  In some browsers, this also destroys global variables.

Instead of `document.write`, try...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){

    var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    img.src = URL[i];
    img.width = 1;
    img.height = 1;
    img.onload = makeHandler(i);

}
```

---

```
function makeHandler(i) {
    return function() {
        getTime(i);
    };
}
```

---

Here's a simple demonstration of the globals being cleared...

In Firefox, the second alert will be `undefined`. In Chrome, the global is retained.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9NbR/

```
window.foo = 'bar';

alert(window.foo); // now we have it

setTimeout(function() {
    document.write('new content');

    alert(window.foo); // now we don't
}, 100);
```

Comment: @AmirReza: I can only assume you've placed the script in the `<head>`... which is *before* the `<body>`. Put it inside the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Although if you're using the `setTimeout`, I'd be surprised if there's no `body` available.

Answer (score -2):

getTime() is a pre-defined function in Javascript please change the name and it should work

Comment: no it does not. I changed it to getTime1 and still same error.

Comment: do you have the page hosted somewhere where in I can take a look at the end HTML being produced

Answer (score -3):

also try using settimeout like this:

setTimeout('func', 100);

does that work better on your browser?

Comment: No, don't pass strings to `setTimeout` :(

Comment: Why not pass string? setTimeout is intended to work with strings. w3schools even uses this in their example of cross browser compliant usage of setTimeout.