# Error keeps coming up with my save and load part, NAN comes up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a save and load part to my little game, and now when I go to mine btc or dash, it goes to NAN.

```js
  var satoshi = 0;
  var hash = 1;
  var litoshi = 0;
  var lhash = 1;
  var updateTimer;
  var minebtcTimer;
  var dhash = 1;
  var dash = 0;
  var mineDashTimer;
  var updatesTimer;
  
  var hashPerSecond = document.getElementsByClassName("hashPerSecond");
  hashPerSecond[0].innerHTML = hashPerSecond[0].innerHTML + " " + hash;
  hashPerSecond[1].innerHTML = hashPerSecond[1].innerHTML + " " + dhash;

  function save() {
    dash = localStorage.getItem("dash");
    dash = parseInt(dash);
    satoshi = localStorage.getItem("satoshi");
    satoshi = parseInt(satoshi);
    dhash = localStorage.getItem("dhash");
    dhash = parseInt(dhash);
    hash = localStorage.getItem("hash");
    hash = parseInt(hash);
  }



  function stops() {
    clearTimeout(updatesTimer);
    clearTimeout(mineDashTimer);
  }

  function minebtc() {
    satoshi = satoshi + hash
    update()
  }

  function updates() {
    document.getElementById('hashers').innerHTML = "Dashosis: " + dash;
    updatesTimer = setTimeout(updates, 10000000000)
    mineDashTimer = setTimeout(minedash, 1000);

  }

  function update() {
    document.getElementById('hashspersecond').innerHTML = "Satoshis: " + satoshi;
    updateTimer = setTimeout(update, 1000000)
    minebtcTimer = setTimeout(minebtc, 1000);
  }

  function minedash() {
    dash = dash + dhash
    updates()
  }

  function stop() {
    clearTimeout(updateTimer);
    clearTimeout(minebtcTimer);
  }

  function boop() {
    localStorage.setItem("satoshi", satoshi);
    localStorage.setItem("hash", hash);
    localStorage.setItem("dhash", dhash);
    localStorage.setItem("dash", dash);

  }
```

```css
.column {
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h6IlzDxjmR0/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

div.div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 120px;
  border: 12px solid yellow;
  padding: 19.5px;
  margin: 19.5px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="save()" onunload="boop()">
  <div class="div">
    Crystals: 0
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <center>
      <h4 class="hashPerSecond">
        Hashs Per Second:
      </h4>
    </center>
    <center>
      <p id="hashspersecond">Satoshis: 0</p>
    </center>
    <button onclick="minebtc()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Mine BTC</button>
    <button onclick="stop()"><img src="kop.png" height=28 width=32>Stop Mining BTC</button>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <center>
      <h4 class="hashPerSecond">
        Hashs Per Second:
      </h4>
    </center>
    <center>
      <p id="hashers">Dashosis: 0 </p>
      <button onclick="minedash()"><img src="dashed.png" height=28 width=32>Mine DASH</button>
      <button onclick="stops()"><img src="dashed.png" height=28 width=32>Stop Mining DASH</button>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you help me it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, it is a value.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and removed some bits an bobs from your code.

`document.write()` as stated on [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239468/function-is-not-defined-after-document-write-called-in-settimeout) notes that `document.write()` causes the `DOM` to be destroyed and in some browsers it causes some `global variables` to be deleted.

Here's the JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/dLtg5pvh/2/